# Remove special char out of a word

Tags: python, string, replace, char

I am trying to count the word frequency in a long string. I have split the string into list of words using string.split() method and remove case sensity by applying string.lower() before splitting the long string. I want to remove some special character such as '!', ':', '.' as those character will mess up the word count. Below is the function that I wrote but it seems not to work properly

```
def clean_word(word):
    replace_list = [':','.',',','!','?']
    s = list(word)
    for i in s:
        for j in replace_list:
            if i == j:
                i=""
print(s) # to see s before it being joined           
word =''.join(s)
return word
print(clean_word('Hello!'))
```

The result is:

['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!']

Hello!

I wonder why "!" has not been replaced with ""? I did put in a test code at line and it shows the comparison works.

```
   if i == j:
       print('Checked')
```

Comment: What is the use in just changing `i` which is just a loop iterator? You need to replace letter of the string.

Comment: Hi Austin, I thought of the issue as you mentioned, but when I tried to print i as looping through s, it did print out "H", "e", ... every time the loop run. What does i represent here? It cannot be a numerical index (as I printed it out to test). Is it a string index or the value itself of the list?

Comment: `i` is letter of string taken one at a time in each iteration. When you do `i = ""`, you are just changing that variable. Original string is untouched.

Comment: Thanks Austin. Get confused about that variable i. You make it clear to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate`:

```
def clean_word(word):
    replace_list = [':','.',',','!','?']
    s = list(word)
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        if x in replace_list:
            s[i] = ""     
    word = ''.join(s)
    return word

print(clean_word('Hello!'))

# Hello
```

If you are interested in a list-comprehension:

```
word = 'Hello!'
replace_list = [':','.',',','!','?']

print(''.join([x for x in word if x not in replace_list]))
# Hello
```

Comment: I need a function as  I will loop through a list of many words and clean each of them. Yours works perfectly, thanks. The list - comprehension is nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved more easily:

```
def clean_word(word):
    replace_list = [':','.',',','!','?']
    for i in replace_list:
        word = word.replace(i,"")
    return word

print(clean_word('Hello!'))
```

Error of your code: in your code you are writing `i=""`, it changes the value of variable `i`, not the original string.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on the variable i.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_word(word):
    replace_list = [':','.',',','!','?']
    new_word = ''
    for x in word:
        if x not in replace_list:
            new_word += x     
    return new_word
print(clean_word('Hello!'))
```

**Output**

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use list comprehension, is faster and cleaner:

```
replace_list = [':','.',',','!','?']

word = "H:e.l,l!o?"

print ''.join([c for c in word if c not in replace_list]) #OUTPUTS: Hello
```